# Android: Quiz App with if else statement

Tags: java, android

I'm a noob, and i need help developing a simple quiz app with if, else statement. I know i've got some problems with my code, but i don't know how to solve them. Even if it doesn't display any error, the app crashes when i try to open the activity called "FirstImageLogo".
An ImageButton should open it. Inside "FirstImageLogo" i put a TextView and a Button, where the user should write the correct answer. If he does, than the button should open a new activity; if he doesn't, than the button should open a Toast message. The message that the user should write down inside TextView in this case is "Facebook". 
Unfortunately i have NO programming knowledge :(
Anyway, here's my "FirstImageLogo.class" code:

```
private EditText inputtxt;
private Button btnNext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_image_logo);

    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View ContentView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name;

                  name=inputtxt.getText().toString();

                 if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("facebook"))
                  {

                        Intent intent = new Intent (FirstImageLogo.this, GoodJob.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                  }
                 else
                  {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, wrong answer. Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }     
            }

            });

    setupActionBar();
}


/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first_image_logo, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And here is the log file:

```
01-17 21:35:39.365: D/dalvikvm(19074): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 1% free 17135K/17236K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
01-17 21:35:39.905: D/dalvikvm(19074): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 1% free 17547K/17604K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
01-17 21:35:39.915: D/AndroidRuntime(19074): Shutting down VM
01-17 21:35:39.915: W/dalvikvm(19074): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41596ba8)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074): Process: com.example.appquiz, PID: 19074
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appquiz/com.example.appquiz.FirstImageLogo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at com.example.appquiz.FirstImageLogo.onCreate(FirstImageLogo.java:28)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-17 21:35:39.915: E/AndroidRuntime(19074):    ... 11 more
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never initialized `btnNext`. use the following

```
btnNext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.id_of_button);
```

then use `setOnClickListener`

Comment: @user3208166 If your problem is solved then mark the tick the answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiate your `btnNext` object.

Hence when doing `btnNext.setOnClickListener`, it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_image_logo);

    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);//add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

`btnNext` is `null` because you haven't initialized it.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_image_logo);

    inputtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idOfButton);  // you need this

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```